# Changing a list inside a function

Tags: r, list

I would like to do perform analysis of structure

```
a <- list()
replicate_letter <- function(letter) {
  return(data.frame(first_letter = rep(letter, 10),
                    second_letter = rep(letter, 10)))
}
get_letter <- function(letter) {
  if (is.null(a[[letter]])) {
    a[[letter]] <- replicate_letter(letter)
  }
  # Do further analysis, plotting,....
}
```

and perform it often just by calling `get_letter`. However, this does not work - function runs, but `a` is not altered.

I have figured out that this is due to attempt to change list inside the function as this

```
a <- list()
replicate_letter <- function(letter) {
  return(data.frame(first_letter = rep(letter, 10),
                    second_letter = rep(letter, 10)))
}
for (letter in letters[1:3]) {
  if (is.null(a[[letter]])) {
    a[[letter]] <- replicate_letter(letter)
  }
}
a
```

runs alright. How do I need to change function `get_letter` to make it work? Is it possible?

Comment: function environments are deleted after the completion of the function. if you want to save what happens inside get_letter, then save it to the global environment with <<- or assign the result of get_letter `result <- get_letter(x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a copy of the list is modified in the function's environment, and that copy is destroyed when the function exits.  R differs in this way from many other languages, in that the global environment is not (by default) modified within functions.

You should have your function return the new list:

```
get_letter <- function(a, letter) {
  if (is.null(a[[letter]])) {
    a[[letter]] <- replicate_letter(letter)
  }
  # Do further analysis, plotting,....

  return(a)
}
```

Calling:

```
a <- get_letter(a, 'c')
```

Comment: This looks good as well. The other answer seems a little bit easier... or is there a reason to avoid "<<-" operator?

Comment: `<<-` breaks the functional paradigm and should be avoided unless there is a very good reason for its use.  Function side-effects make code hard to understand and make debugging difficult.

Comment: @Love-R Assigning the result of a function is the normal way of using R. For example to calculate an average you would assign it: `result <- mean(c(1,2,3))`. You wouldn't just type `mean(c(1,2,3))` and hope it gets assigned to some variable. But `<<-` can be used if you feel it works best for you.

Comment: As my code will be also used by others, I go for this way.

Comment: @Love-R I think you are doing a disservice to SE because this is not an answer to your question. It is an answer to your requirement. 
The answer to the question is not "don't do it", it is simply using <<-
Perhaps, warning that this solution has a disadvantage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your situation, so perhaps take this with a grain of salt.  But be aware that you are assigning the output of `a[[letter]] <- replicate_letter(letter)` *only* within the function (which then disappears afterwards).  You could try [?<<-](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) instead.  Consider:

```
replicate_letter <- function(letter) {
  return(data.frame(first_letter = rep(letter, 10),
                    second_letter = rep(letter, 10)))
}
get_letter <- function(letter) {
  if (is.null(a[[letter]])) {
    a[[letter]] <<- replicate_letter(letter)
  }
  # Do further analysis, plotting,....
}
get_letter("a")
a
# $a
#    first_letter second_letter
# 1             a             a
# 2             a             a
# 3             a             a
# 4             a             a
# 5             a             a
# 6             a             a
# 7             a             a
# 8             a             a
# 9             a             a
# 10            a             a
```

The help for `<<-` reads (in part):

> **The operators <- and = assign into the environment in which they are evaluated.** The operator <- can be used anywhere, whereas the operator = is only allowed at the top level (e.g., in the complete expression typed at the command prompt) or as one of the subexpressions in a braced list of expressions.
>
> **The operators <<- and ->> are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned. If such a variable is found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined**, otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment. Note that their semantics differ from that in the S language, but are useful in conjunction with the scoping rules of R. See ‘The R Language Definition’ manual for further details and examples.

(The boldface is mine.)

Comment: Splendid! This works! I didn't know about <<-  operator.

Comment: Upvoting Your answer as it does the job and explains the concept. Thanks!